# Unable to login into Ubuntu.com on Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome

Recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.  During installation created an account in ubuntu.com.  Able to login into ubuntu.com using built in Firefox browser but not able to login on Chrome browser.

Tried to paste the error screenshot but a message I am not allowed to paste pics.[login error in chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n930.png)

Comment: Hi Srini,

If you're absolutely sure you're using the correct login details, I suggest you file a bug on the website.

On the bottom of the page, there's a link (look for: "Report a bug on this site"), that will allow you to do that.

Comment: @DiogoConstantino, thanks for your response.  Today I checked again and it worked.  I am sure it did not work till yesterday even after many attempts, but today it worked.  Thankyou very much.  This question can be considered solved.